# How to hide the username in magit-log?

Tags: magit

Trying to utilize a small screen, and I did this once before, so I know it's possible.

How to hide the username in magit-log so that only the commit message is visible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can hide the margin by calling `magit-toggle-margin`
(<kbd>LL</kbd> as of verion 2.9.0, <kbd>Lt</kbd> previously).  To
change the default visibility, you can customize `magit-log-margin`:

```
Documentation:
Format of the margin in ‘magit-log-mode’ buffers.

The value has the form (INIT STYLE WIDTH AUTHOR AUTHOR-WIDTH).

If INIT is non-nil, then the margin is shown initially.
STYLE controls how to format the committer date.  It can be one
  of ‘age’ (to show the age of the commit), ‘age-abbreviated’ (to
  abbreviate the time unit to a character), or a string (suitable
  for ‘format-time-string’) to show the actual date.
WIDTH controls the width of the margin.  This exists for forward
  compatibility and currently the value should not be changed.
AUTHOR controls whether the name of the author is also shown by
  default.
AUTHOR-WIDTH has to be an integer.  When the name of the author
  is shown, then this specifies how much space is used to do so.
```

Running `customize-apropos` with "magit margin" will show a list of
the other margin-related options.